# Is there a way to not return the `by` column as the first column in a data.table grouping

Tags: r, data.table

If I group-by using the `by` keyword in data.table it always returns the `by` column as the first column.  Is there a flag/option to tell it not to do this?  Or a clever way of getting rid of it?

In particular I want to group and then `rbindlist` to my original table, so infact the issue could also be said as - "how to stop it reordering the columns"

For example:

```
DT = data.table(I = as.numeric(1:6), N = rnorm(6), L = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 2))
DT[, list(I = mean(I), N = mean(N)), by= L]
DT
```

gives:

```
> DT[, list(I = mean(I), N = mean(N)), by= L]
   L   I          N
1: a 2.5  0.4291802
2: b 3.5  0.6669517
3: c 4.5 -0.6471886
> DT
   I          N L
1: 1  1.8460998 a
2: 2  0.7093438 b
3: 3 -1.7991193 c
4: 4 -0.9877394 a
5: 5  0.6245596 b
6: 6  0.5047421 c
```

As far as the `rbindlist` request goes, it would be nice to be able to do this:

```
DT = rbindlist(list(DT, DT[, list(I = mean(I), N = mean(N)), by= L]))
```

or perhaps

```
DT = rbindlist(list(DT, DT[, list(I = mean(I), N = mean(N), L), by= L]))
```

or something similar (neither of which work)

Comment: (+1) I'd *really* like for the columns to be returned in the same order as well!

Comment: Carone, @Arun, ok +1 now added to [FR#1757](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240&atid=978&func=detail&aid=1757).

Comment: @MatthewDowle, thanks for adding this feature to the todo list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't particularly like this auto-column-reordering as well. The "trick" I usually do is to use `setcolorder` after obtaining the output as follows:

```
DT <- data.table(I = 1:6, N = rnorm(6), L = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 2))
DT.out <- DT[, list(I = mean(I), N = mean(N)), by= L]
```

Here, `setcolorder` as:

```
setcolorder(DT.out, names(DT))

#      I            N L
# 1: 2.5  0.772719306 a
# 2: 3.5 -0.008921738 b
# 3: 4.5 -0.770807996 c
```

Of course this works if the names of `DT` are the same as `DT.out`. Else, you'll have to specify the column order explicitly as:

```
setcolorder(DT.out, c("I", "N", "L"))
```

**Edit:** Since you'd like to bind them by rows immediately, yes, it would be nice to not have this as an intermediate result. And since `rbindlist` seems to bind by position, you could use `rbind` which binds by column names and `data.table` tells this as a warning and suggests to use `use.names=F` if you want to instead bind by position. You can safely ignore this warning.

```
dt1 <- data.table(x=1:5, y=6:10)
dt2 <- data.table(y=1:5, x=6:10)

rbind(dt1, dt2) # or do.call(rbind, list(dt1, dt2))

#      x  y
#  1:  1  6
#  2:  2  7
#  3:  3  8
#  4:  4  9
#  5:  5 10
#  6:  6  1
#  7:  7  2
#  8:  8  3
#  9:  9  4
# 10: 10  5
# Warning message:
# In .rbind.data.table(...) :
#   Argument 2 has names in a different order. Columns will be bound by name for 
#   consistency with base. Alternatively, you can drop names (by using an unnamed 
#   list) and the columns will then be joined by position. Or, set use.names=FALSE.
```

Comment: +1 but yes I had thought of that but I want to do rbind list immediately and so it would be nice not to have to store the intermediate just to reorder the columns (I'll add this to the question to make it clearer.

Comment: I think `rbind` takes care of column reordering automatically?

Comment: seems like `rbindlist` drops column names to bind by position, which is different from `rbind` on `data.frames` which, if identical column names exist in different order, merges appropriately.